# LINQ: multiple levels

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine that a library contains many books that have many pages. I've got the Library object, which has a HashSet of books, that have a List of page objects. How can I, using LINQ, calculate how many pages there are in the library?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Very interesting answers which are not best practice are upvoted and accepted!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what makes them not best practice? The answer that was accepted had the count1 what seems to me to be the same way as your answer?

Comment: non of the Jeff, answers are pure linq, there is no `Count` property in linq it's for list (you can't use it everywhere), also just first one (which is like my answer) is Clean to understanding meaning of code without thinking about it(clean code), and ulrichb is not good like Jeff, other answers.

Comment: @Saeed: I could have easily changed using the `Count` properties of the collection types I had assumed to using the `Count()` extension methods, except I knew the concrete types of the collections.  Doing so doesn't make it any less LINQ than not.

Comment: @Jeff M, because niklassaers says he has a list, I didn't downvoted you, but it's not good, if it was a database object may be cause programmer use ToList and bad things happen. and also I answered before you by this approach, and your other approach is just saying you are knowing linq well, but they aren't really good ways.

Comment: @Saeed: If it was some other type, I would use the appropriate methods for it.  _If_ using `Count()` or whatever was the way to go, then I would use it of course.  But trying to generalize using a single, universal solution to a whole family of problems is not the answer, it all depends on the many variables that make up the problem.  In this case, the types of the collections being one of them.  The code used _must_ change depending on the requirements of the problem. ...

Comment: ... Nik unfortunately didn't give us examples of what he has, only described it.  But it's enough information to provide good solutions, whether you agree with it or not.

Comment: @Saeed: For what it's worth, I took time to qualify my answer since Nik left out some crucial details.  We were likely to be writing our answers at the same time, only I took a bit longer.  I included other possible queries, not because yours is less correct nor _just_ to get more attention, but it was because as I mentioned, there are many ways to do this with the same performance characteristics.  I just tried to include the ones that were most relevant.  Please don't look at it as if I was trying to one-up you, there was a question and I provided an answer and that's all there is to it.

Comment: @Jeff M, today (not all day) really I'm not interested in getting upvote (because yesterday I lost around 10 up because I exceed daily limit), in this case I just try to say `using LINQ` in this question means pure thing, yes it's not good do all things by the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the types as you describe are something like this:

```
class Library
{
    public HashSet<Book> Books { get; }
}

class Book
{
    public List<Page> Pages { get; }
}
```

There are a number of ways in which you can write such a query.

```
Library lib = ...;

var count1 = lib.Books.Sum(b => b.Pages.Count);
var count2 = lib.Books.Select(b => b.Pages.Count).Sum();
var count3 = lib.Books.Aggregate((sum, book) => sum + book.Pages.Count);
// etc.
```

Of course there's many ways in which you can formulate this.  Personally I'd write it using the first method.

Comment: +1, though I'd prefer `(from book in lib.Books select book.Pages.Count).Sum()`

Comment: @Gabe: To each his own.  Though it's worth noting that that query is equivalent to the second version, just expressed using query notation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = library.Books.SelectMany(book => book.Pages).Count();
```

or equivalent:

```
var count2 = (from book in library.Books
              from page in book.Pages
              select page).Count();
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it has to count each Page individually instead of just adding up the page counts of each Book.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = library.books.Sum(x=>x.pages.Count())
```